# Inline Dropdowns with Labels on top

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

Im trying to make two dropdowns inline (which I got working) with labels on top of each other (not working). I also want the two to be same width.

This is how far I got:

```
<span class="ui inline">
    <label for="roles">Add roles to user</label><br>
    <select id="roles" multiple="" class="ui dropdown">
        <option value="">Roles</option>
        <option value="Role1">Role 1</option>
        <option value="Role2">Role 2</option>
        <option value="Role3">Role 3</option>
    </select>
    <label for="sites">Add sites to user</label>
    <select id="sites" class="ui dropdown">
        <option value="">Sites</option>
        <option value="Role1">Site 1</option>
        <option value="Role2">Site 2</option>
        <option value="Role3">Site 3</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Heres a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67sq63rt/10/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wasn't sure if you specifically wanted to use the Semantic UI *inline* class to handle your inlining, so I continued to use it in this example.

The `inline` class is usually paired with `fields` inside a `ui form`.

```
<div class="ui form">
<span class="inline fields">
    <div class="field">
    <label for="roles">Add roles to user</label><br>
    <select id="roles" multiple="" class="ui dropdown">
        <option value="">Roles</option>
        <option value="Role1">Role 1</option>
        <option value="Role2">Role 2</option>
        <option value="Role3">Role 3</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label for="sites">Add sites to user</label><br>
    <select id="sites" class="ui dropdown">
        <option value="">Sites</option>
        <option value="Role1">Site 1</option>
        <option value="Role2">Site 2</option>
        <option value="Role3">Site 3</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nw949qwz/

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the information! I tried fields before but not in a form since I didn't plan to submit all at once. But I guess I don't have to.